# MVC Framework for ASP.net 3.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am currently stuck with ASP.net 3.0, which means that I cannot use ASP.net MVC and ADO.net EF. While I can replace EF with Subsonic or ActiveRecord, I wonder what you guys recommend for MVC? I am interested in nice URLs and separation between View and Controller, two things that I always found hard with Webforms.

For now, I will give [Castle MonoRail](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/index.html) a spin, but if you have more suggestions i'd be happy as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Castle MonoRail](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/index.html) seems indeed to be the only serious MVC Framework for .net 2.0/3.0, so I'll go with that.

Comment: that's what i would suggest. y cant you use 3.5?

Comment: Not my server, no control over what goes on it and what not.

Comment: I was looking into Castle MonoRail myself. I'd say that it's your best bet at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There's a hacky, unofficial, unsupported workaround that allows you to deploy ASP.NET MVC on .NET 2.0 (and possibly .NET 3.0).

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I believe to remember that this did not work with the MVC beta anymore, but I did not double check. Really hacky though